# How to Convert Nested Function to Class Function?

Tags: typescript, leaflet, arrow-functions

I have an nested function that I would like to split out into a class function, but am having an issue using "this" in the class function. I believe that because of how the function is called, the scope of "this" changes, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

**Nested:**

```
private test() {
   this._map.on('overlayadd', function(eventLayer: L.LeafletEvent) {
           console.log(this.test);
       });
   }
}
```

**Class:**

```
private test() {
   this._map.on('overlayadd', this.onOverlayAdd); 
}

private onOverlayAdd(eventLayer: L.LeafletEvent) {
   console.log(this.test);
};
```

I tried using an arrow function to "fix" the scope, but now the code in the function doesn't even seem to be reached.

```
this._map.on('overlayadd', () => this.onOverlayAdd);
```

Comment: `this._map.on('overlayadd', () => this.onOverlayAdd); ` If you want to do this approach, you need to call the function inside your new arrow function. Ie, `this._map.on('overlayadd', (eventLayer) => this.onOverlayAdd(eventLayer));`

Comment: Yes - do the arrow function, but fix it as Nicholas says.

Comment: That worked! Thank you both.